# Digit problem $a,b$

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, contest-math, problem-solving, decimal-expansion

Find two numbers $ a$ and $b $ such that the digits of b are the same digits as a in
another order and the number $a − b$ has all the digits equal to $1$?

What I thought:

A first natural serial thought where each digit of the corresponding $ a $ number in the $ b $ number is one more, but when we have to put the largest $ a $ digit in $ b $ we realize that subtraction is not possible to give $ 1. $.
So another idea is to use the next digit in your favor. For example, when we subtract $ 80 - 79 = 1 $, because if we weigh the subtraction of each house individually, we realize that $ 0 $ uses a dozen of $ 8 $ to subtract it. Thinking this way and doing some examples to get a better view we get the desired $ a $ and $ b $ numbers.
Let $ a = $ $987654320$, $ b =$ $ 876543209 $. It is easy to see that $ a $ and $ b $ have the same digits and they are not in the same order. It is also evident after subtracting that reasoning makes sense, since $ a - b = 111111111 $.
 I don't know if I could clearly show my thinking.

Comment: This seems correct, what's the question?

Comment: Find two numbers a and b such that the digits of b are the same digits as a in another order and the number a−b has all the digits equal to 1?

Comment: It seems though that you have already solved this with $a=  987654320, b= 876543209, a-b = 111111111$.